# What day is it? vs. what date is it?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Google search result for both questions are the same: `Tuesday, June 6, 2017`. I wonder if I can use these 2 sentences interchangeably.

> What **day** is it?
>
> What **date** is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not interchangeable, as they ask different things.

> What day is it?

Tuesday.

> What date is it?

[Tuesday] the 6th of June, 2017.

---

That being said, it's possible that when you ask

> What day is it?

that the person who responds has realized that you're looking for the date, rather than the name of the current day.
*For example, when you're filling in a form and it's obvious that you need to write today's date.*

But that's an inference on their part, and not inherently understandable from just your question (without any surrounding context).

Comment: "What day is it?" may generate the answer "It is today". However, I think it is better asked: _"What day / date is **today**?"_

Comment: @virolino: The top half of my answer focuses on pedantic correctness, the bottom half focuses on the _commonly understood_ interpretation of the phrase. We can argue about what would be a more precise phrasing but it doesn't really change the fact that people colloquially use "what day is it?" to ask for a date.

Comment: @virolino: Also, I consider "Today" a willfully obtuse answer as it's always correct and doesn't actually provide any information. It may be pedantically grammatically correct but it is not actually answering the request for information that was posed.

Comment: "Today" a willfully obtuse answer - totally agree. I do not live (and never did) in an English speaking country, so "What day / date is it?" is not very familiar. But "What day / date is today?" is more common around - including interactions with people from other non-English speaking countries, in professional context.

Answer (score 3):

For my opinion, sometimes they can be used correctly interchangeably but you cannot always use these two sentences interchangeably because each one of them may have a totally different meaning.

Google indeed gives the same answer for both sentences, but as you know google is limited with its [artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) and it can be seen well on Google translate...

Well, notice that the meaning of:

> What day is it?

may refer to each one of the following:

- **Day in a week**: Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat.
- **Day in a month**: 1st, 2nd, 3rd... - 31th.
- **Characters**: Hot, cold, bad, good, etc.
- **Holidays**: Father's day, Mother's day, Family day etc.

while:

> What date is it?

may refer to:

- a numbered day in a month
- a sweet fruit of various types of palm tree

see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/date) more meanings for the word "date".

[image]

Anyway, in the end of the day you can conclude by yourself that it is not always can be used interchangeably:)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the top answer.

They are NOT interchangeable ... !!!

What day is it? Always refers to the DAY OF THE WEEK.

What date is it?  Refers to wanting to know what date of the month/year it is.

For example in **Australia or UK** we say and write the following:

**12th of January, 2019 or 12-01-19/2019**
[[ Most people use only the 19 for the year, but I use the long version of the year most of the time, Depending on space requirements.]]

**American numeric order would be  -  01-12-19/2019**

I'm only guessing here, but they probably say the month first over there as in January 12 2019 if not fully numeric...

They call it 9/11 which to me is 11th of September  11-09-01
Aussie here though :)

Have a good one